# Clang. How to overcome "unknown builtin" error message

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-construction, clang

I have a program that setups clang compiler instance and adds include paths using HeaderSearchOptions class. When I run ParseAst on the input file libavutil/samplefmt.c (from ffmpeg package), I get the following message on the screen. Basically, it is not able to resolve some (gcc?) builtin functions. How do I get rid of this error? In general, If setting include path through HeaderSearchOptions, how do I ensure I don't miss out on all include paths from my gcc installation?

Thanks!

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 .
 /usr/include/freetype2
 /usr/include/fribidi
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include/clang/Basic
 /opt/llvmrelease/bin/../lib/clang/3.4/include
 /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu
 /include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
In file included from libavutil/samplefmt.c:19:
libavutil/common.h:258:12: error: use of unknown builtin '__builtin_clz'
    return av_log2((x - 1) << 1); 
           ^
libavutil/intmath.h:89:23: note: expanded from macro 'av_log2'
#define av_log2       ff_log2
                      ^
libavutil/intmath.h:45:29: note: expanded from macro 'ff_log2'
#   define ff_log2(x) (31 - __builtin_clz((x)|1))
                            ^
libavutil/samplefmt.c:59:14: error: use of unknown builtin '__builtin_strlen'
        if (!strcmp(sample_fmt_info[i].name, name))
             ^
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/string2.h:804:22: note: expanded from macro 'strcmp'
      && (__s1_len = __builtin_strlen (s1), __s2_len = __builtin_strlen (s2), \
                     ^
libavutil/samplefmt.c:59:14: note: did you mean '__builtin_strchr'?
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/string2.h:804:22: note: expanded from macro 'strcmp'
      && (__s1_len = __builtin_strlen (s1), __s2_len = __builtin_strlen (s2), \
                     ^
libavutil/samplefmt.c:59:14: error: use of unknown builtin '__builtin_strcmp'
        if (!strcmp(sample_fmt_info[i].name, name))
             ^
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/string2.h:807:9: note: expanded from macro 'strcmp'
```

Answer (score 4):

Something must have gone funny when you did your project configuration.  The `ff_log2` code, for example, is inside:

```
#if HAVE_FAST_CLZ && AV_GCC_VERSION_AT_LEAST(3,4)
```

So you need to make sure `HAVE_FAST_CLZ` isn't defined, and you should be ok on that front.  You can do similar things to fix the `strcmp`.

Comment: Thanks. I have the following line in config.* files                 `#define HAVE_FAST_CLZ 1`.                                      When I remove that, it is compiling. But what surprises me is that when I compile the project directly throuhg gcc, I don't get a built in error (with HAVE_FAST_CLZ set to 1). Could you tell me why it happens only when I setup clang and add include paths, it doesn't work? I am pretty sure I am adding all include paths, so its unlikely to be the reason.

Comment: Builtins can be directly defined by the compiler without the symbols actually being present in any include files.  Instead, the compiler has an internal list of "builtins" that it will look for and handle when compiling.

Comment: @Brian, I kind of get the idea of a builtin. But in this case, what surprises me is that when I invoke clang directly, I don't get the error but when I invoke through my program by setting up compilerInstance, I get the errors. Do I need to add ay paths while setting up? Here is a link to my code... http://pastebin.com/cc0rMFr6